# adb shell force-stop restarts android 6.0 device

Tags: android, bdd

I am using appium to run set of of BDDs on android 6.0, I noticed following command

adb shell am force-stop

cause android 6.0 ( phone / tablet ) to restart.

Any hints ?

Comment: Is that the whole command you're running?  I think it needs the package name after it.

Comment: Yes, try giving any package name from installed apps